# SQL error adding a row that isn't unique, and only has FK's

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm building a web app and I noticed whenever I try to add a row to one of my relationship tables (a table consisting of only an Id and 2 FK's as columns) I get an error and the row isn't added. When I add the row manually using SSMS I get this error

> This row was successfully committed to the database. However, a problem occurred when attempting to retrieve the data back after the commit. Because of this, the displayed data in this row is read-only. To fix this problem, please rerun the query.

[image: Sql Error]

This only happens when I enter a row and the FK's are the same. If I execute it, the row gets added like expected. But from my web app it throws an error and the row doesn't get added. I don't have any constraints so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Can anyone explain this? And does anyone know of a workaround for my web app? I'm using ASP.NET Core 3 and EF6.

Comment: I'm having difficulty in understanding. Do you face errors when using SSMS or when using WebApp ?

Comment: Both, SSMS gives me the error in the picture and the WebApp throws an exception that the row couldn't be added.